# Guess Counting Control

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm starting my studies in Python and I was assigned the Task to write code for a guessing game in which I have to control the total tries the player will have. I've described the functions, they're working (I believe...haha) but I can't make to "reset" the game when a wrong guess is input...
I wrote this:

```
guess_count = []
count_control = 1
def check_guess(letter,guess):
    if guess.isalpha() == False:
        print("Invalid!")
        return False
    elif guess.lower() < letter:
        print("Low")
        return False
    elif guess.lower() > letter:
        print("High")
        return False
    elif guess.lower() == letter:
        print("Correct!")
        return True
    else:
        print("anything")

def letter_guess(guess):
    check_guess ('a',guess)
    while len(guess_count) <= 3:
        if check_guess == True:
            return True
        elif check_guess == False:
            guess_count.append(count_control)
            guess = input("Try again \n")

letter_guess(input("test: "))
```

UPDATE: I rewrote the code after some insights from other users and readings and came up with this:

```
class Game:

number_of_attempts = 3
no_more_attempts = "Game Over"

def attempt_down(self): #This will work as the counter of remaining lives.
    self.number_of_attempts -= 1
    print('Remaining Lives:',self.number_of_attempts)
def check_guess(self,letter): 
    """
    Requires
    letter - a letter that has to be guessed
    guess - a input from the user with the guessed letter
    """ 
    while self.number_of_attempts > 0:
        guess = input ("Guess the letter: ")
        if guess.isalpha() == False:
            print("Invalid!")  
        elif guess.lower() < letter:
            self.attempt_down()
            print("Low") 
            print("Try Again!")  
        elif guess.lower() > letter:
            self.attempt_down()
            print("High")  
            print("Try Again!")
        elif guess.lower() == letter:
            print("Correct!")
            return True
            
    print (self.no_more_attempts)
    return False    


game = Game()
"""   
This is used to run the game. 
Just insert the letter that 
has to be guessed.
"""
teste1 = game.check_guess('g')
teste2 = game.check_guess('r')
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your problem is that you don't know how to end the game after a certain amount of guesses?

Comment: A quick note, you have an error in your letter_guess function where you are checking: `if check_guess == True`. You will need paranthesis and two arguments with check_guess. The way you have it you are not calling the function...just comparing a function object itself to see if it is equal to True...which can't be what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rub is in that you have a state of a game that you are tracking as global variables `guess_count` and `count_control`

This is an example of why python and other languages provide classes and objects:

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.guess_count = []
        self.count_control = 1

    @staticmethod
    def check_guess(letter, guess):
        if guess.isalpha() == False:
            print("Invalid!")
            return False
        elif guess.lower() < letter:
            print("Low")
            return False
        elif guess.lower() > letter:
            print("High")
            return False
        elif guess.lower() == letter:
            print("Correct!")
            return True
        else:
            print("anything")

    def letter_guess(self, guess):
        self.check_guess('a', guess)
        while len(self.guess_count) <= 3:
            if self.check_guess('a', guess) == True:
                return True
            elif self.check_guess('a', guess) == False:
                self.guess_count.append(self.count_control)
                guess = input("Try again \n")

game = Game()
game.letter_guess(input("test: "))

game = Game()
game.letter_guess(input("test: "))
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew! I started my studies 6 days ago and Python is the first language i'm learning. I'll definitely check out classes and objects. My next challenge will be implement the input for two players. One you input the letter and the other will have to guess it. I tried your code and it worked great. I just don't understand why is it printing "High" or "Low" three times in the first attempt and two times in the following attempts...

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you wanted better. The check_guess method will print something every time it is called, and it seems you did not want it called more than once in the letter_guess method. I think what you may have intended was to store the results of your call to check_guess, you can do this lie so: `guessed_right = self.check_guess('a', guess)`.  And afterward you can then say `if guessed_right:` for your conditional. You do not have to say `if guessed_right == True:` btw

Comment: But still I don't think that `letter_guess` will be doing what you want. I can't see the point of doing the while loop there at all if you only make the check once. Going to avoid the temptation to rewrite the whole thing, because I think that going through the struggle is how you learn. Not too bad for 6 days though. It does get eaiser with practice.